# How do I replace the spaces between words in Emacs?

Tags: regex, search, text, emacs, replace

I have a files consisting of words:

```
ndkjsank ndjksandknsakj                                     
dnsjakndjskndjknsakjn dsajkndksnakjndsnajkndjkas 
dsnjak    a
```

And I would like to replace the (sometimes multiple) spaces between them with a single tab:

```
dsnak**\t**ndsjka
njdkas**\t**ndksjankda
njdsaibdusai**\t**nkdsnakjdnas
```

Is this possible using a regular expression in Emacs? I thought I might get away with using a rectangular selection area but the words are of varying length (and the file is far too long to do it manually).

EDIT:

This comes close but it also selects the spaces/newlines/tabs to the right of the second word:

```
\s-
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regexp you want is  `+`. Call `M-x replace-regex` then replace  `+` with `\t`. Note there's an empty space before the + sign.

Also, to produce the tab you might have to hit the <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-i</kbd> keys. I'm not sure if it accepts the `\t` syntax when called interactively.

Comment: Genius, thanks! I didn't notice the space at first but it works.